# Lightweight Python IDE for ML

Tags: python, c++, debian

I run Debian 9 with 2GB of RAM. I primarily use the machine to access AWS for training models. I use jupyter notebooks to prototype and atom to finalize models.But, Atom is a resource hogging text editor. What would be a great IDE for python which has Jupyter integration and is light weight?

I am aware of the Hydrogen package in atom. I prefer Jupyter notebook as it's more convenient to deploy Jupyter as server and have ssh sessions running else where.

I use C++ to build faster models. Is there an IDE that supports both python as well as C++ and has Jupyter integration?

Comment: Have you looked at Visual Studio Code?  Its a very nice editor and serves as a IDE for python and other languages.  Jupyter is supported by Hydrogen modules.

Comment: @jmh Visual Studio Code supports Hydrogen modules?

Comment: yes.i use the Hydrogen package in both VScode and Atom.

Comment: @jmh Tried VScode, apparently Debian just freezes and waits until some memory is freed whenever I compile a C++ code. I have to restart the system.

Comment: That's not good. VScode is pretty popular so I'm surprised by this. If you have no luck you may go to the Visual studio code site and pose the question there or see if you get an answer from this site.  You could also ask another question about the results you got when trying to use visual studio code.  Sorry.